# Oбъясните почему массив не выводит значения?

Tags: javascript

```js
var goods = ['апельсин', 'мандарин', 'яблоко', 'вишня', 'слива']

//Так не выводится на экран

goods.length = 'компьютер'

console.log(goods)

//Так выводится на экран 

goods[goods.length] = 'Компьютер'
console.log(goods)
```

Как добавить элемент в конец произвольного массива?

Что лучше использовать `goods[goods.length] = 'Компьютер'` или `goods.push('компьютер')` ?

Comment: лучше почитать документацию)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Обращение к свойствам объекта возможно через (точку и свойство) и через (квадратные скобки и строку с названием свойства).

Обращение к элементам массива - только через квадратные скобки с индексом элемента.

```js
var obj = { prop0: "apple", prop1: "orange" };
console.log('obj["prop1"]:', obj["prop1"]);
console.log('obj.prop1:', obj.prop1);

var arr = [ "apple", "orange" ];
console.log('arr[1]:',arr[1]);
//console.log('arr.1:',arr.1); - syntax error
```